# How to store returned values from oracle in c# List?

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to store the returned values from the oracle table in C# string List.

My query will return so many records, I want to store all the returned records in C# `List<string>`.

Can any one give some idea on this?

Comment: Show us what code you've got, and we may show you how to adapt it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you just need an idea, you can use [OracleDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter.aspx) to fill out a `DataTable` from your database. Later you can use an extension method called `AsEnumerable` on that `DataTable` to get an `IEnumerable`, and then you can turn that into a list with the `ToList` extension method. And now you have a **list** of your data from the database.

```
List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

If you need a list of `string` then you may use a LINQ query on your `DataTable`, project the result to an anonymous type of `string` field and then use the `.ToList()` method on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling any stored procedure or returning a DataSet from a query, then you can iterate over the Rows in DataTable in the DataSet in a Foreach loop and keep storing the values in the C# List.